# How to get Total count of Records from Kafka Topic and Save into HDFS?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-kafka, spark-streaming-kafka

All,

I am working on consuming data from Kafka on dump into HDFS. I am able to consume data and wanted to get the total counts of records from Kafka and save as a file into HDFS so that i can use that file for the validation. I was able to print records in console but i am not sure how can i create the file of total count?

Query to pull records from Kafka:

```
Dataset ds1=ds.filter(args[5]);
 StreamingQuery query = ds1
                   .coalesce(10)
                   .writeStream()
                   .format("parquet")
                   .option("path", path.toString())
                   .option("checkpointLocation", args[6] + "/checkpoints" + args[2])
                   .trigger(Trigger.Once())
                   .start();

          try {
                query.awaitTermination();
            } catch (StreamingQueryException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
```

and the code that i have written to get the records and print in console:

`Dataset stream=ds1.groupBy("<column_name>").count();` // Actually, I wanted to get the count without using GroupBy, i have tried `long stream=ds1.count()` but i was encounter with the error.

```
 StreamingQuery query1=stream.coalesce(1)
                        .writeStream()
                        .format("csv")
                       .option("path", path + "/record")
                       .start();

               try {
                    query1.awaitTermination();
                 } catch (StreamingQueryException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(1);
                }
```

This is not working, can you please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The number of records at any time in a topic is a moving target.

You would need to use old Spark Streaming to find number of records *per Spark partiton batch*, then use an `Accumulator` to count all records processed, but that would be the closest your could get.

Spark + Kafka is claimed to have exactly once processing semantics, so I would suggest you focus on error capturing and monitoring over just count validation.